# Sind »multimodal« und »intermodal« synonym im Personenverkehr?

Tags: difference, word-choice, synonym, technical-terminology

Ich möchte das Mobilitätsverhalten eines Menschen beschreiben. Er benutzt im Laufe eines Tages mehrere Verkehrsmittel. Bewegt er sich *multimodal* oder *intermodal*?

Wenn ich den Wikipedia-Artikel zur [Multimodalität](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimodalit%C3%A4t) richtig verstehe, bewegt er sich *multimodal*, da

> *Multimodales Verkehrsverhalten einer Person ist die tatsächliche Nutzung unterschiedlicher Verkehrsmittel in einem bestimmten Zeitraum.*

Der Artikel gibt allerdings zu, dass

> Der Begriff der Multimodalität im Personenverkehr wird im Bereich der Verkehrswissenschaften bislang nicht einheitlich und oftmals synonym mit dem Begriff der Intermodalität verwendet.

Im Wikipedia-Artikel zum [Intermodalen Verkehr](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermodaler_Verkehr) findet sich der Personenverkehr daher überhaupt nicht.

Trotzdem muss man im Internet nicht lange suchen, um Dokumente zu finden, in denen namhafte Universitäten intelligente ÖPNV-Verkehrskonzepte als *intermodal* beschreiben. Tatsächlich scheint *intermodal* in dem Zusammenhang häufiger zu sein als *multimodal*.

Sind die Begriffe bezogen auf den Personenverkehr tatsächlich synonym? Gibt es Bereiche, in denen auf die Unterscheidung tatsächlich wert gelegt wird? Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen den Begriffen, der mir bisher nicht aufgefallen ist?

Comment: Scheint mir allerhöchstens für Zug- und Autofähren Bedeutung zu haben; vielleicht noch für Kurswagen bei unterschiedlichen Spurweiten. Ansonsten steigen Passagiere doch selbst um. Und selbst auf Fähren müssen sie oft aus Sicherheitsgründen aussteigen.

Comment: Hier ist ein Artikel der den Unterschied sehr ausführlich herausarbeitet: http://multi-mobility.tumblr.com/post/60830879635

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Einklang mit dem, was hiergiltdiestfu in seiner Antwort geschrieben hat, würde ich für jemanden, der *im Laufe des Tages* mehrere Verkehrsträger wählt, lieber *multimodal* schreiben.

*Intermodaler Verkehr* beschreibt laut der ersten Zeile des [Wikipediaartikels](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermodaler_Verkehr):

> **Intermodaler Verkehr** ist eine Unterart des multimodalen Verkehrs und beschreibt eine mehrgliedrige Transportkette, bei der ein und dieselbe Transport- oder Ladeeinheit mit mindestens zwei verschiedenen Verkehrsträgern befördert wird.

Demnach bewege ich mich *nur dann* intermodal, wenn ich *für einen Weg* mehrere Verkehrsmittel in Anspruch nehme.

Beispiel:

- Ich fahre in der Früh mit dem Bus zur Arbeit. Am späten Nachmittag fahre ich mit der Tram (einmal umsteigen) und meinen Kollegen ins Kino. Nach dem Film fahre ich mit dem Bus – wieder mit einem Mal umsteigen – wieder nach Hause.

  Mein Tag war *multimodal,* weil Busse und Trams drin vorkommen. Jeder einzelne Verkehrsweg war allerdings *monomodal* – erst einmal Bus, später einmal Tram, nochmal später einmal Bus. Dass ich von einem Bus in einen anderen umgestiegen bin, macht den einzelnen Verkehrsweg nicht *intermodal.*
- Ich fahre in der Früh mit dem Bus zur Arbeit. Weil ich länger arbeite, verpasse ich am Abend den letzten Bus und fahre einen Umweg, wobei ich erst eine Tram in die Stadt nutze, und direkt im Anschluss einen Bus aus der Stadt heraus.

  Der Tag war wieder *multimodal.* Außerdem war der zweite Weg, der Heimweg, zusätzlich auch *intermodal,* denn ich bin direkt von der Tram in den Bus umgestiegen, habe also zwei verschiedene Verkehrsträger benutzt.

Vekehrsverbünde haben natürlich einmal die Absicht, dass Menschen möglichst oft mit ihnen – also mit Bus, gegebenenfalls Tram, gegebenenfalls Zug, vielleicht auch ergänzungsweise Taxi – fahren. Das heißt, dass ihnen natürlich an *multimodalen* Kunden gelegen ist. Gleichzeitig ist es allerdings ein oft nicht so gut verwirklichtes Ziel, dass ein einzelner Verkehrsweg *intermodal* ablaufen kann: Dass man also mit dem Bus zum Bahnhof fahren kann, dort nahezu nahtlos in einen Zug (S- oder Regionalbahn) umsteigen kann, und am nächsten Bahnhof direkt Anschluss an die Tram bekommt. Das verlangt, die Fahrpläne aufeinander abzustimmen und demnach ein höheres Maß an Planung als lediglich linienbezogen zu planen – bietet aber mehr Fahrkomfort, da Fahrgäste irgendwann das Vorhandensein von Anschlüssen verinnerlichen. Zum Beispiel vereinfacht der Abend- und Nachttakt in Braunschweig intermodales Fahrverhalten, da alle oder ein großer Teil der Linien am Rathaus aufeinander warten und gleichzeitig in alle Richtungen abfahren; ein Vollknoten.

Demnach haben viele Universitäten, Verkehrsverbünde und Verkehrspolitiker vieles Intelligentes und weniger Intelligentes zur Intermodalität geschrieben, während die Multimodalität von den gleichen Personengruppen eher als gegeben angenommen wird, sofern das entsprechende Angebot da ist. Das erklärt die hohe Dichte an Veröffentlichungen, die den Begriff *intermodal* enthalten, wie du feststellst.

Ich würde die Begriffe sauber trennen und gegebenenfalls in Studien in einem Anhang auch sauber definieren, damit keine Unklarheiten auftreten können.

---

Disclaimer: Ich bin verkehrspolitisch aktiv.

Answer (score 5):

Kein Verkehrswissenschaftler: Als Laie bzw. Informatiker hätte ich *multimodal* für Deine Intention sofort verstanden – mehrere Transport-Modi eben.

*Intermodal* klingt hingegen seltsam und trägt für mich nicht dieselbe Bedeutung wie multi-. *inter-* ist zwischen – zwischen zwei Modi? OK, in Richtung „verbindet zwei oder mehr Modi“, aber (a) hätte ich da länger drüber nachdenken müssen und (b) fühlt sich das so an, als würde es dann eben direkt um die Verbindung der Modi gehen, also z. B. dass die Person die S-Bahn zum Flughafen benutzt hat und nun vorgehoben werden soll, dass der Übergang nahtlos im Flughafenterminal-S-Bahnhof passiert ist.

Eine Person, die morgens mit der Straßenbahn zur Arbeit fährt und abends mit dem Taxi von der Arbeit in die Oper, würde da vom Gefühl nicht unter *intermodal* fallen, wohl aber unter *multimodal* – im Laufe des Tages mehrere, aber nicht inhärent verknüpfte Transportmodi. Echte Synonyme würden eine solche Unterscheidung nicht ermöglichen.

Da nach Deiner Aussage in dem zugehörigen, wissenschaftlichen Feld beide Begriffe Verwendung finden, die Begriffsfindung aber noch nicht abgeschlossen scheint, wäre ich im wissenschaftlichen Umfeld unbesorgt, die beiden Begriffe synonym zu verwenden und so vielleicht an der Begriffsbildung mitzuwirken, aber für einen allgemeinsprachlichen Text würde ich es der Verständlichkeit halber vorziehen, nur *multimodal* zu verwenden.

Comment: Die Verknüpfung mehrerer Modi ist vielleicht tatsächlich der feine Punkt, der den Begriff _intermodal_ bei den intelligenten Verkehrskonzepten rechtfertigt und damit zu meiner Verwirrung beigetragen hat.

Answer (score 1):

Intermodal ist im Güterverkehr ein zu stehender Begriff, als dass er mMn legitim auf Personenverkehr anwendbar wäre. Und dort ist auch der Fakt, dass das transportierte Gut eben nicht umgeschlagen wird, zentral (Ich mag übrigens diesbezüglich das Beispiel mit dem Kurswagen von oben). Hier würde ich lieber sehen, dass die Nutzung mehrerer Verkehrsmittel als Multimodal tituliert wird. Die Anwendung von Intermodal kommt mir effekthascherisch vor.